# @storybook/angular cannot load scss file on stories index

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass, storybook

I have been trying to use storybook for my angular project and I use this guide https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-angular/
I use the recommended config for webpack for sass loader for scss files and the scss file related to the project works fine, but if I import a scss file in the stories index.ts file, this file it is not loaded.

**stories/index.ts**

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/angular';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { VideoPosterComponent } from '../src/app/modules/ui-common/video-poster/video-poster.component';
//This scss it is not loaded
import '../src/styles.scss';

storiesOf('Video Poster component', module)
  .add('Video Poster with author data', () => ({
    component: VideoPosterComponent,
    props: {
        title: "Cinemagraph With Custom title",
        subtitle: "This is a custom subtitle!"
    }
  }))
  .add('Video Poster without author data', () => ({
    component: VideoPosterComponent,
    props: {}
  }));
```

**.storybook/webpack.config.js** (recommended in here --> https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-angular/#configure-style-rules)

```
const genDefaultConfig = require('@storybook/angular/dist/server/config/defaults/webpack.config.js');

module.exports = (baseConfig, env) => {
  const config = genDefaultConfig(baseConfig, env);

  // Overwrite .css rule
  const cssRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test && rule.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/');
  if (cssRule) {
    cssRule.exclude = /\.component\.css$/;
  }

  // Add .scss rule
  config.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  });

  return config;
};
```

And, the scss file for my component was loaded without problems

**src/app/modules/ui-common/video-poster/video-poster.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-poster',
  templateUrl: './video-poster.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-poster.component.scss'] // this were loaded without problems
})
export class VideoPosterComponent implements OnInit {
  private hostUrl = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/video.gallereplay.com/portfolio/clients';
  private baseUrl = `${this.hostUrl}/jaegermeister/Cinemagraph_plain/1920x1080`;

  @Input()
  public videoUrls = {
    poster: `${this.baseUrl}/cinemagraph.jpg`,
    mp4: `${this.baseUrl}/cinemagraph.mp4`,
    webm: `${this.baseUrl}/cinemagraph.webm`,
  }
  @Input() public title = 'Custom Cinemagraph Productions';
  @Input() public subtitle = 'Exclusive Content for Businesses';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Repository:
https://github.com/gpincheiraa/storybook-components-sample

run `npm install && npm run storybook` for check storybook running.

**What I am doing wrong??**

Answer (score 4):

I assume that, like me, you're looking for a way to load global styles from SASS files into an Angular Storybook. I know it's been a while since you asked, but I came across this solution while searching for a way to accomplish this: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6364#issuecomment-485651328.

Basically, you can load your global styles in the Storybook config file. However, you need to use inline webpack loaders in the import path so Storybook will load them properly.

```js
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/styles.scss';
```

That did the trick for me. In the end I didn't have to bother with the custom webpack config. Hopefully that solves your problem!

Comment: I have tried same but, it did not work for me. I have a custom scss file at root level which imports other scss, few mixins and angular material typography. Although I was not getting error,. but styles are not getting applied! Here you can find details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247632/how-to-load-global-scss-files-in-storybook-for-angular-app

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to import an scss file from your typescript. You must include it from your scss.

Please remove :

```
//This scss it is not loaded
import '../src/styles.scss';
```

In your scss file add :

```
@import "styles.scss";
```

In you angular.json add :

```
"styles": [
     "src/styles.scss",
 ],
 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
          "src/" // maybe not required in your case
        ]
  },
```

In you .storybook/webpack.config.js please try :

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["sass-loader"],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Otherwise there is the possibility to add an alias as Xdecus said here https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3814#issuecomment-401756776

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/')
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All style imports must be in Component metadata (specifically in styles or styleUrls field). You're trying to import style file as js file, which is wrong.