# Compiling SCSS in Storybook with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, gatsby

I have an existing GatsbyJS project and I want to add Storybook to this project to showcase each separate component. I'm using SCSS in my project, which are being compiled with `gatsby-plugin-sass`, which works great. However, I can't use my components in Storybook since it cannot compile the `SCSS` files.

I followed the instructions from both Storybook and GatsbyJS. This is how my storybook/webpack.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {

  // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
  config.module.rules[0].exclude =
    [
      /node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/,
    ];

  // use installed babel-loader which is v8.0-beta (which is meant to work with @babel/core@7)
  config.module.rules[0].use[0].loader = require.resolve('babel-loader');

  // use @babel/preset-react for JSX and env (instead of staged presets)
  config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.presets = [
    require.resolve('@babel/preset-react'),
    require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
  ];

  config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins = [
    // use @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties for class arrow functions
    require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),

    // use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove static queries from components when rendering in storybook
    require.resolve('babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries'),
  ];

  // Prefer Gatsby ES6 entrypoint (module) over commonjs (main) entrypoint
  config.resolve.mainFields = ['browser', 'module', 'main'];
  return config;
};
```

and my storybook/config.js file looks like this:

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
configure(require.context('../src', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);

// Gatsby's Link overrides:
// Gatsby defines a global called ___loader to prevent its method calls from creating console errors you override it here
global.___loader = {
  enqueue: () => {
  },
  hovering: () => {
  },
};

// Gatsby internal mocking to prevent unnecessary errors in storybook testing environment
global.__PATH_PREFIX__ = '';

// This is to utilized to override the window.___navigate method Gatsby defines and uses to report what path a Link would be taking us to if it wasn't inside a storybook
window.___navigate = pathname => {
  action('NavigateTo:')(pathname);
};
```

I assume I need to add a sass-loader to the webpack config, however it does feel a bit unnatural to add another custom loader since GatsbyJS already handles my SCSS files.

I've been fiddling with adding sass-loader, css-loader and style-loader to my webpack.config.js, but I couldn't get it to work.

Also Googling this specific situation doesn't give me a lot of hits. I assume I'm not the first person who tries to do this.

Comment: I don't know if It will help but this is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795872/storybook-angular-cannot-load-scss-file-on-stories-index?rq=1

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/sass/ and https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sass/ Are you adding the plugin to your gatsby-config?

Answer (score 2):

install this npm package:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

and then in the **.storybook** folder create a file with **webpack.config.js** name and paste these configs on this file:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.

I solved it by removing my `styles.scss` from my `layout.js` as this was causing errors due to not having loaders in Storybook. I then instead included styling in 2 separate locations, one for Gatsby and the other for Storybook which is now working well.

For Gatsby I have included styling in `gatsby-browser.js` as below:

```
import "./src/styles/styles.scss"
```

And for Storybook in `.storybook/preview.js` as:

```
import "!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/styles.scss"
```

Adding loader support.

I think Amir Jafari's answer above should also work well.

I have used this method as I also use it to add support for the `:focus-visible` polyfill for visually testing components in Storybook so I feel this method can be useful for including other packages as well if a suitable Gatsby plugin is not (yet) available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by installing `@storybook/preset-scss` and adding that to the storybook "addons" list (I did not install the additional sass or loader dependencies), and also by modifying storybook's `main.js` file to import my global styles.