# How to load Global scss files in storybook for angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, sass, storybook

I am trying to load a custom global style file, theme-default.scss in storybook.
Although my components are loading in storybook but styles are not being applied.I followed this tutorial [Storybook official docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) of custom webpack config. (I am not very familiar to webpack though)

here is my .storybook/main.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
//import '!style-loader!css-loader!../src/stories/stories.scss'; // for scss
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.ts'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-notes'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  }
};
```

It is giving me following error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'var api = require("'
        on line 1 of D:\code2\mawani\mawani-angular-client\dpd-billing\src\app\app.component.scss
>> var api = require("!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStyle
   ^

 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 45:18-49 45:61-92 45:104-135 45:147-178
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/stories/containers/SearchBar.stories.ts
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.ts[\\/]?)$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/preview.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true ./src/theme-default.scss ./src/styles.scss

ERROR in ./src/app/modules/feature/public/page-not-found/page-not-found.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'var api = require("'
        on line 1 of D:\code2\mawani\mawani-angular-client\dpd-billing\src\app\modules\feature\public\page-not-found\page-not-found.component.scss
>> var api = require("!../../../../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime
   ^

 @ ./src/app/modules/feature/public/page-not-found/page-not-found.component.ts 12:18-60 12:72-114 12:126-168 12:180-222
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/stories/containers/SearchBar.stories.ts
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.ts[\\/]?)$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/preview.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true ./src/theme-default.scss ./src/styles.scss

   ^
```

Then, I tried using inline loader syntax as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6364#issuecomment-485651328)
Here is how my .storybook/preview.js looks

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./_common.scss';
```

Inside _common.scss

```
@import '../src/theme-default.scss';
@import '../src/styles.scss';
```

Although it is not giving any error but still styles are not getting applied!

Here is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "xyz": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/xyz",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme-default.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "xyz:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz:build"
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "xyz:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "xyz:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "xyz",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": ""
  }
}
```

I have also tried using [this approach sass-resources-loader](https://coder.rocks/javascript/storybook-js-custom-webpack-setup-for-scss-sass/)

I have done a lot of trial and error but could not figure out solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a codesandbox with minimal reproducible example of your code so it would be easier for people to help you. Thanks!

Comment: I import them using inline exactly how you did. FOr the sake of trying, maybe you could import a simple independent "css" file with a simple CSS rule to see if that works. If it does, you will narrow down the problem on the loader or in your scss files

Comment: var api = require("!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStyle Where this lines come from? your scss or from sass-loader nodemodule? Try to update or rollback to a previous version of this module. If you can provide a sandbox it will be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Since Angular 13 and onward, style imports must be added to your **storybook-architekt** in your angular.json, under **your-project** > **(build-)storybook** > **options** > **styles**. As importing the stylesheets in *.storybook/main.js* is no longer supported, you can remove it and instead add the stylesheets like shown below.

angular.json:

```json
"your-project": {
  ...
  "storybook": {
      "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
      "options": {
          ...
          "projectBuildConfig": "your-lib:build-storybook",
          "styles": [
              "path-to-the-stylesheet/styles.scss",
              "path-to-the-stylesheet/your-theme.scss"
          ],
          ...
      },
      ...
  
    },
    ...
}
```

You can find this information in the [migration-guide](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#64-angular-changes) of storybook.

Answer (score 0):

For storybook versions below 6.4.*:
If `theme-default.scss` is used in your app, then you can simply import it into your Angular app's global `styles.scss` file.